Karate support for Java performance testing over Scala
Now that gatling supports java, I was wondering if there were any plans to convert or add support for java performance test setups?
https://www.knowledgehut.com/blog/programming/scala-vs-java
https://gatling.io/blog/java-kotlin-or-scala-which-gatling-flavor-is-right-for-you

Some technical differences between Java, Kotlin & Scala:

Scala and Kotlin are less verbose than Java
Scala and Kotlin compilers are way slower and have more CPU usage than the Java compiler
Scala requires an extra (free) IntelliJ IDEA plugin that's not installed by default
Scala and Kotlin require extra maven and gradle configurations, while Java is set for both out-of-the-box. This point is mitigated by all the demo projects we provide to get you started.
Scala is the only one of the three that works with sbt, the interactive build tool for Scala that is supported by Gatling


Using this answer Peter Thomas recently left on a different karate-gatling related question -
"Refer to the "TODO" example - here is the link to the karate-1.5 branch, where you can use the Java DSL instead of Scala: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-todo/tree/karate-1.5 "

link is no longer valid - `404 - page not found
Cannot find a valid ref in
karate-1.5"`

my mistake, the end quotation mark was being added to the hyperlink on accident. I updated the answer but here is the link again just in case.
https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-todo/tree/karate-1.5
